# TensorFlow model gets loss 0

Tags: python, tensorflow, cross-entropy

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
def weight(shape):
return tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1))
def bias(shape):
return tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape))
def output(input,w,b):
return tf.matmul(input,w)+b
x_columns = 33
y_columns = 1
layer1_num = 7
layer2_num = 7
epoch_num = 10
train_num = 1000
batch_size = 100
display_size = 1
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,x_columns])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,y_columns])

layer1 = 
tf.nn.relu(output(x,weight([x_columns,layer1_num]),bias([layer1_num])))
layer2=tf.nn.relu
(output(layer1,weight([layer1_num,layer2_num]),bias([layer2_num])))
prediction = output(layer2,weight([layer2_num,y_columns]),bias([y_columns]))

loss=tf.reduce_mean
(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y,logits=prediction))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
for epoch in range(epoch_num):
   avg_loss = 0.
   for i in range(train_num):
      index = np.random.choice(len(x_train),batch_size)
      x_train_batch = x_train[index]
      y_train_batch = y_train[index]
      _,c = sess.run([train_step,loss],feed_dict=
{x:x_train_batch,y:y_train_batch})
      avg_loss += c/train_num
   if epoch % display_size == 0:
      print("Epoch:{0},Loss:{1}".format(epoch+1,avg_loss))
print("Training Finished")
```

My model gets
Epoch:2,Loss:0.0
Epoch:3,Loss:0.0
Epoch:4,Loss:0.0
Epoch:5,Loss:0.0
Epoch:6,Loss:0.0
Epoch:7,Loss:0.0
Epoch:8,Loss:0.0
Epoch:9,Loss:0.0
Epoch:10,Loss:0.0
Training Finished

How can I deal with this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` expects labels in one-hot form, i.e. with a shape `[batch_size, num_classes]` . Here, you have `y_columns = 1`, which means only 1 class, which is necessarily always both the predicted one and the 'ground truth' (from your network's point of view), so your output is always correct no matter what the weights are. Hence, `loss=0`.

I guess you do have different classes, and `y_train` contains the ID of the label. Then `predictions` should be of shape `[batch_size, num_classes]`, and instead of `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` you should use [`tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits)

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer taught me that I had made a mistake about input classes. I have been able to predict!